# Sort a list of objects based on second value of list attribute

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of Car objects, each object being defined as follows:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, vin, name, year, price, weight, desc, owner):
        self.uid = vin
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.price = price
        self.weight = weight
        self.desc = desc
        self.owner = owner
        self.depreciation_values = self.get_depreciation_values(name, vin)
```

The depreciation_values attribute is a list that has 8 components, like below:

```
[-12.90706937872767, -2.2011534921064739, '-17', '-51.52%', '-7', '-2.75%', '-5', '-1.74%']
```

The second value (-2.2011534921064739) denotes the depreciation factor and is what I'm trying to use as the sort key.

I'm aware of attrgetter:

```
car_list.sort(key=attrgetter('depreciation_values'))
```

But this would sort the list based on the first value of depreciation_values and not the second.

Is there a way to sort all the objects based on the depreciation factor?

Comment: @Delgan 'operator.attrgetter' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: @L3viathan Oups, indeed. wilkesybear is the best solution anyway.

Comment: @Delgan It could totally be made working, but I guess it'd be too much magic for the standard library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can instead use a lambda in order to access the exact value you want on which to sort:

```
car_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.depreciation_values[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a [`__lt__()` (less than) method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) and other comparison methods to return a boolean based on your desired sort attribute then you could use the built-in sorted() or `list.sort()`. ["... sort routines are guaranteed to use `__lt__`() ... "](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#odd-and-ends)

```
class Car:
    ...
    def __lt__(self, other):
        self.depreciation_values[1] < other..depreciation_values[1]
```